# iOS - Render camera data in OpenGL ES2 take 50-75% of CPU usage

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, cpu-usage

I am rendering video on `GLKView` with `OpenGL ES 2.0` on a demo project. The code is followed from this project [iOS+Objective-C: Create a real time photo filter app](http://altitudelabs.com/blog/real-time-filter/) . I just created a sample project, start camera and render the data on `GLKView` skipped the filtering part of that project. My CPU usage is as high as 70-76%. Is not it too high?? GPU should perform much faster. How do I render in OpenGL with less CPU usage? Any resource link will be appreciated

Comment: iOS is very active at trying to save battery, if you're hitting your frame rate target, it will reduce the amount of juice it gives to the CPU and GPU. It makes those CPU/GPU usage counters very hard to understand, because you don't know if you're looking at 70% of a full-speed CPU, or 70% of a CPU that's only running at 10% of its capacity.

Comment: I don't know what's happening. Our full app working with network communication , sending and receiving live video and displaying on screen only take 30-40% of cpu but I wanted to change the video player to OpenGL but the demo project take 70% cpu which only take camera data and show . What's wrong I have done?